# where does this warning come from in Stage?

Tags: simulation, stage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, all! I am learning a multi-robot collision avoidance algorithm by using simulator Stage.

please see following image:
[image: image description]

I think the yellow warning( exclamation mark) is saying that two robots crash with each other.
I want to know where the code in Stage that this warning comes from, or in other words: what kind of topic is published when a collision is detected and which callback function in Stage is for response when a message( like topic?) about detecting collision is published?
Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192067/where-does-this-warning-come-from-in-stage?/) by [scopus](https://answers.ros.org/users/8561/scopus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 279 on 2014-09-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As a general note, the best source for Stage details is github, but it's embedded in [model_draw.cc](https://github.com/rtv/Stage/blob/f9c59ca77f203049979dcf32223e5d2b26c03bf2/libstage/model_draw.cc#L378).
stageros doesn't publish this information. The condition is identified in [model_position.cc](https://github.com/rtv/Stage/blob/f9c59ca77f203049979dcf32223e5d2b26c03bf2/libstage/model_position.cc#L602).

You could modify [stageros.cpp](https://github.com/ros-simulation/stage_ros/blob/master/src/stageros.cpp#L428) to detect when a model is stalled (collisions) and to publish a message on a topic.

As a final note, you could also just evaluate the */robot_X/odom* message and compare the observed velocity to the intended velocity of the robot. (Compare the embedded twist message to the twist command that you issued.)

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) with karma: 2022 on 2014-09-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [scopus](https://answers.ros.org/users/8561/scopus/) on 2014-09-09**:
Thank you very much for your attention. So do you mean the warnning is from /robot_x/stall topic?  I don't know how to display /robot_x/odom topic and /robot_x/cmd_vel topic. These two topics can't be displayed in rqt_plot. And It is very hard to watch them in terminals by inputing "rostopic echo..”

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2014-09-13**:
Your robot controller could subscribe to the odom topic (it's already publishing to the the cmd_vel topic). Since it knows what the robot should be doing, it can detect that the commanded velocities are not being observed. `rostopic list` should let you know all the topics that you can use.

**Comment by [scopus](https://answers.ros.org/users/8561/scopus/) on 2014-09-19**:
sorry, I can't understand your guidance. I don't know how to compare the observed velocity to the intended velocity of the robot. I also can't get any signal about the yellow warning by displaying  topics /robot_x/odom and /robot_x/cmd_vel or comparing them. Would you like to explain more clearly?

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2014-09-19**:
If you issue a Twist message with a non-zero velocity and the observed velocity is zero (your robot isn't moving), then you can infer that you've hit an obstacle. For willow-four-erratics.world, /robot_0/odom provides information about robot_0. Subscribe to it and compare with the desired value.

**Comment by [scopus](https://answers.ros.org/users/8561/scopus/) on 2014-09-23**:
Although the yellow warning indicates a collision, but the speed of robot is not zero. It is very hard to see a collision is happenning if no yellow warning exists. This is why I said I couldn't compare those topics of /robot_x/odom and Twist message to find some inconsisitencies.  Thank you